# Print a box with the single center @ replaced by a space

Tags: java

I don't know what to do for this. Print a box with a hole in its center. That is, print a box as in normally  but with the single `@` in the center (or one close to the center for boxes with an even width) replaced with a space.

I have the box. How do I calculate the center of the box?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class square {
    public square(){
        Scanner H=new Scanner(System.in);
        int y=H.nextInt();//int for width
        int x=H.nextInt();//int for height
        int [][]shape=new int[x][y];//2d array stores the above
        for(int i=0; i<shape.length; i++){//loops through height and width below
            for(int j=0; j<shape[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print("@");//prints box of @

                }

            System.out.println();
            }

        }


    public static void main(String[]args){
        new square();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you move (most of) your title to the body of your question?  It is confusing as presently constituted.

Comment: sorry, about that. one moment

Comment: i dont know how to edit my question

Comment: There should be an `edit` link beneath where your `java` tag is displayed.

Comment: yeah, i have been clicking that with out success. i might need to do it on a different web browser

Comment: If I was 100% certain what you were asking, I would do it for you.  But as it is, I'm not completely sure what your requirements are.

Comment: Hi when printing I get the box with width & hight depending on your input. I want to know how would I get just the singular center @ to be blank  (or one close to the center for boxes with an even width). thanks

Comment: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~ztomasze/ta/ics111-fa09/A12/PrintingBoxes.java

Comment: question 4 from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, not sure why you are making an array (shape) at all, unless that is part of your assignment?

If you use a for loop that steps from 0 to y inside one that steps from 0 to x instead of using the lengths of the array, you will get the same results without needing the array.

As for the center, its location is x/2, y/2.  If you change your inner loop to check your variables i and j to see if the current position is x/2, y/2 and print a space instead of an @ in that case, I think you will have the results you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, no this is not a assignment. i was just trying to get my self familier with arrays and 2d arrays. so i should create an exception in a if statement checking for x/2 and y/2?

Comment: Yep, that should work fine. It will be right for odd dimensions at least, for even there is no exact center character but it will be the lower of the center 2.  You dont need a Java Exception for this if that is what you meant, just a regular if/else structure.

Comment: if(i==x/2 && j==y/2){
     System.out.print(" ");
    }
    else {
     System.out.print("@");
    }
    
    }

Comment: the above worked wonders for me. thanks alot man..i know use of 2d arrays isnt prohibited for this sort of program but i was trying to make things harder for my self. lol thanks

Comment: You got it.  That looks fine to me.